# Ставится ли дефис в слове "рыбоовощные"?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, орфография, грамотная-речь, слитно-дефис

Дефис в слове "рыбоовощные". Если да, то почему. Если нет, то почему.

Answer (score 2):

На практике встречаются **обе формы**, но форма "рыбооовощной" является более употребительной. В словаре есть варианты: рыбоконсервный, рыбокрабоконсервный.

Аналогичные проблемы возникают со словами "хлебобулочный и мясо-молочный".

1) **К дефисному написанию** таких слов нас склоняет **сочинительная связь** основ (рыба и овощи), слово получено сложением основ прилагательных, но при этом первая основа усечена на суффикс Н: рыб(н)о-овощной.

**2) Слитное  написание** объясняется тем, что образуется новое слово способом бессуффиксального сложения: рыб/о/ овощ/н/ой.

Поэтому здесь **важна традиция написания и частотность употребления**. Например, **хлебобулочный**: хлеб и булки ― это практически хлебные изделия, написание слитное; **мясомолочный**: мясо и молоко ― разные продукты, дефисное написание.

В сочетании "рыбоовощной" **овощи ― это только добавка**, а не самостоятельный компонент, поэтому лучше писать слитно.